# TabHost in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

### I am trying to intigrate Tab-Host into Android

- I am getting  error as i have posted in logcat
- Any ideas on how to overcome this
- The JSON response and other things are perfectly fine as it works
  well without tabhost but as i have intigrated the tabhost below i am
  having errors

**AndroidTabAndListView.java**

```
public class AndroidTabAndListView extends TabActivity {

    // TabSpec Names
        private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Inbox";
        private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Outbox";
        private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Profile";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

            // Inbox Tab
            TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
            Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            // Tab Content
            inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

            // Outbox Tab
            TabSpec PriceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
            Intent PriceIntent = new Intent(this, PriceDescriptionActivity.class);
            PriceSpec.setContent(PriceIntent);

            // Profile Tab
            TabSpec DistanceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
            Intent DistanceIntent = new Intent(this, DistanceDiscriptionActivity.class);
            DistanceSpec.setContent(DistanceIntent);

            // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
            tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); 
            tabHost.addTab(PriceSpec); 
            tabHost.addTab(DistanceSpec); 
        }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:7004/";
    TextView timedisplay;
    String item;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> TimeMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    ListView yourListView;
    List<Item> yourData = new ArrayList<Item>();
    MyAdapter customAdapter;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String restaurant_name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        timedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RestaurantTimeID);

        yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
        // Instantiating ProgressDialog with onCreate method


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();


    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Please Wait", true, false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String _response = null;
            String _response1 = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
                        CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
                JSONArray first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");
                JSONArray second_array = jsonObject
                        .getJSONArray("RestaurantTimings");
                for (int i = 0; i < first_array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = second_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Item item = new Item();

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    int id = c.getInt("_id");
                    String TIME = c.getString("RestaurantTime");
                    item.setTime(TIME);

                    c = first_array.getJSONObject(i);

                    String NAME = c.getString("restaurantNAME");
                    item.setName(NAME);

                    yourData.add(item);
                }

                HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
                        CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            customAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.itemlistrow, yourData);
            yourListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    item = yourData.get(position).getName();

                    // String sendingurl="url1?param1=value1";

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            RestaurantDesc.class);
                    i.putExtra("REST", item.toString());
                    // i.putExtra("key", yourData.get(position).getUrl());
                    //i.putExtra("CC_RES", item.toString());
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Logcat::**

```
09-18 15:37:50.366: D/AndroidRuntime(553): Shutting down VM
09-18 15:37:50.366: W/dalvikvm(553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.findmybuffet/com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabAndListView}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:198)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.project.findmybuffet.AndroidTabAndListView.onCreate(AndroidTabAndListView.java:40)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-18 15:37:50.385: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  ... 11 more
```

From the error it says "You must specify a way to make tab indicator" .... but how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `indicator` like `inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC);`for each tab as below:

> ```
>        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
>         // Inbox Tab
>         TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
>         Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
>         inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC);       <----------- Set the indicator 
>         // Tab Content
>         inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);
>
>         // Outbox Tab
>         TabSpec PriceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
>         Intent PriceIntent = new Intent(this, PriceDescriptionActivity.class);
>         PriceSpec .setIndicator(OUTBOX_SPEC);   
>         PriceSpec.setContent(PriceIntent);
>
>         // Profile Tab
>         TabSpec DistanceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
>         Intent DistanceIntent = new Intent(this, DistanceDiscriptionActivity.class);
>         DistanceSpec .setIndicator(PROFILE_SPEC);  
>         DistanceSpec.setContent(DistanceIntent);
> ```

Comment: @ GrlsHu ..... Perfect... your solution works ..... Just for my knowledge i want to ask .... why do we need to set the indicator .... is it compolsary ?

Comment: Indicator defines the each tab individually. So its necessary to provide each tab indicator so that at the time of tabs selection each tabs will gets identified individually from other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The indicator tells the tabspec what to display.

You could, for example, inflate a layout into it...

```
DistanceSpec.setIndicator(inflater.inflate(layout.distance_tab, null));
```

and have distance_tab.xml have something like....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
android:background="#00ffffff">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/layout_distance_tab"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_drawable"
    android:layout_height="60dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_tab_icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_width="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_distance_drawable"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="10.5dip"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_tab_indicator"
        android:text="Distance"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```